# Query would run directly on MySQL but not through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple MySQL query

```
select * from tutor where verified = 0 and alert_by < '2015-08-05' LIMIT 0,1
```

Now, running this directly through phpMyAdmin provides the desired results, however, when this query is being executed through a set of PHP statements, it doesn't return anything. Below is my code in PHP

```
$this_date = date("Y-m-d");

$query = "select * from tutor where verified = 0 and alert_by < '$this_date' LIMIT 0,1";

$contact = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = $contact->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

However, the `$row` is empty, I can't seem to figure this out. I know this seems trivial, but its a little annoying.

**Note:** Removing `"and alert_by < '$this_date'"` from the query, works fine.

Comment: And what's the result of `mysqli_query`?

Comment: Please check the note section of my question, if the error was with `mysqli_connect()`. The query wouldn't run at all.

Comment: We need more informations. var_dump $conn, $contact and show us

Comment: Ok, could you try to `var_dump($query);` right after `$query` declaration?

Comment: Here: `string(76) "select * from tutor where verified = 0 and alert_by < '2015-08-05' LIMIT 0,1"`

Comment: You you try to pass that string directly as second argument of `mysqli_query`, so: `mysqli_query($conn, 'select * ..._;`

Answer (score 0):

Check

1. Connection

   ```
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
   ```
2. Use [`mysqli_query`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) like this

   ```
   $contact = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tutor where verified = 0 and alert_by < '$this_date' LIMIT 0,1");
   ```
3. Use [fetch array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) like this (*Example #2 Procedural style*)

   ```
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($contact, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
   ```

Comment: Tried all, still no luck.

Comment: Can you tell what is wrong with what Namit has written? There could be n other ways of writing a code but the point is you should tell whats wrong with his code?